# What does “here it comes”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was listening a popular youtube video Steve Jobs insult and when one of the audience said to Steve, you are a bright and influential man, Jobs said “here it comes” Why he is saying here it comes ? What is the meaning and why audience is laughing ?

Comment: I have a guess, but I don't like guessing. Why don't you supply a link so the context is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Here it comes" means that you think something important will happen next.

By saying this, Jobs identifies the man's comment as *preparation* for whatever he will say *next*. In other words, Jobs knows that the audience member didn't raise his hand only to compliment him.

One possible implication is that the next thing will be negative, since people often "soften" something negative by saying something positive first. Jobs may expect a question about why he did or said something stupid, or he may simply expect a very hard question that matches the compliment — for example, if he's brilliant he should be able to answer why Apple has less than 10% market share in laptop computers.